# Why is the average shot damage global statistic so high?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I just beat normal, again with variable damage and variable upgrades and some of the other settings.

At the end of the game it compares your stats to the worlds.
One that jumped out is I did about 6.94 damage per shot where the worlds average damage was 16.xx

How is that possible?

I wish I took a screen shot

Comment: I imagine it's a combination of squad choice and how quickly you upgrade your weapons (and how long you play after full upgrading them). I believe users which modify their DefaultGameCore.ini to increase the damage output of weapons would be factored into the average damage as well.

Comment: If it doesn't detect for modding, one player who made his weapons do 1 billion damage could have ruined the stats for everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets look at the nice [weapons table](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons_%28XCOM:_Enemy_Unknown%29#Weapon_Comparison_Chart) on the XCOM:EU Wiki. The average damage for any weapon is nowhere near 16.xx. Even with the 100% bonus of [HEAT ammo](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/HEAT_Ammo) and similar abilities, it would be difficult to get a single weapon to consistently generate a damage of 16+. Let alone, average ~16+ across all weapons.

If we assert that damage above 16 is rare in vanilla XCOM:EU, that can suggest that modding maybe responsible for biasing the World's average damage.

[image: XCOM Weapons]

Comment: That is just sad.

Answer (score 5):

The World Statistics are a little bit borked because there is little validation done of the records submitted (just look at the tens of thousands of "average" scientists).

While it's impossible to determine how this statistic is calculated without delving into the code (do Rockets count as shots? Is Rapid Fire one "shot" or "two"), it *is* possible to do **More** than this in a single shot:

A heavy with HEAT ammo shooting at a Shredded target, for instance, can easily do upwards of 30 damage. Plasma Snipers and Crit-Specced Assaults can also break into the 20s, if properly set up.

So while my bet is on mods for many of the "outlier" statistics, it is certainly *plausible* for average damage to be that high, especially if Rockets count as a single shot.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that people could just avoid ending the game for a long time and keep running more and more missions with maxed out troops.

Taking numbers from: http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Damage_(EU2012)&oldid=45621

An Assault Colonel with Killer instinct and Bring 'em On and an Alloy Cannon will do 16-30 damage (crit presumed) depending on the number of targets and the order these modifiers are applied.

```
(15 + 5) * 1.5 = 30
(15 * 1.5) + 5 = 27
(10 * 1.5) + 1 = 16
```

An Assault Colonel with Killer instinct and an Alloy Cannon does 15-20 damage (crit presumed).

A Sniper with Headshot and a Plasma Sniper rifle does 19-21 damage on a crit.